# Excluding a string in a url in Htaccess URL redirect

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, concatenation

I'm trying to to change some URL formats for good while want to exclude some URLs:

`myurl.come/usa/(.*)` ---> `myurl.come/usa/(.*)+2014`

while `myurl.come/usa/music-events/`   will stay the same.

This is what I need but don't know how to write it properly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^usa/music-events [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} usa/(.*)

RewriteRule ^usa/(.*)    /usa/Concat($1,2014 )            [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/usa/music-events
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/usa/(.*)-2014
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/usa/(.*)
RewriteRule ^usa/(.*)$ /usa/$1-2014 [R=301,L]
```

This will change `usa/sometitle` to `usa-sometitle-2014`, but I won't change `/usa/music-events`

Comment: Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer? @user1952378

Comment: This is not written in maintenance friendly manner, just count how many times `usa` word has been repeated in this rule. What if same rules needs to be repeated for `ca`?

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(usa)/((?!(?:music-events|2014)).+)$ /$1/$22014 [R=301,L,NC]
```